# How do i overcome missing values when matching a dataframe with a list in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big dataframe (called df) that that contains some values for locations. This is a shortened version:

```
          locations          Value1  Value2  Value3 Value4
 0        s-Hertogenbosch    58        2       91     23
 1        Aachen             10        2       17     8
 2        Aalsmeer           50        50      50     0
```

Moreover, I have got a list(called list) containing 50 locations; some of these locations appear in the dataframe and some do not. For every location in the 'List', I want to find Value1 which corresponding to that location. I do this by matching the locations of the 'list' and the dataframe with the following code:

```
p=[]    
for y in range(50):
    p.append(df.loc[df['locations'] == List['Location'][y], 'Value1'].item())
```

For simplicity, I first create a vector p which stores the value1 of each location. This code works when the location given in the list can also be found in the dataframe. However. if the location given in the list cannot be found in the dataframe, I get an error. I would like to assume a value for those cases. Does anyone know how to code this?

Comment: Do you mean`df.loc[df["locations"].isin(other_location_list), "Value1"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (I did a simple example):

```
import pandas as pd


locations = ['s-Hertogenbosch', 'Aachen', 'Aalsmeer']
v1 = [58, 10, 50]
v2 = [2, 2, 50]
v3 = [91, 17, 50]
v4 = [23, 8, 0]
df = pd.DataFrame(locations, columns=['locations'])
df['Value1'] = v1
df['Value2'] = v2
df['Value3'] = v3
df['Value4'] = v4

list_with_locations = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'Aachen']

l = list(df[df['locations'].isin(list_with_locations)].Value1)

print(l)
```

Comment: accept and upvote this answer if it helped